# Removing white space and blank line from local text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
ShowOwi

g exsu n

Sierouz

nicee99
```

This is the content extracted from a image screenshot and saved 
as text file called B&W1.txt

I am trying to remove the blank spaces in line to append these into a list
using the following js code

```
        var filename="../static/R6scoreex/extract/B&W1.txt"
        $.get(filename,function(txt){
            var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            len = lines.length;
            for (var j = 0 ; j < len; j++) {
                //save(lines[i]);
                if((lines[j]!='') && (  lines[j]!='undefined')){

                    $('#Text'+i).append("<li>"+lines[j]+"</li>");

            }

        });
```

but still the empty string is getting inserted

Comment: where u get variable `i` in this line
`$('#Text'+i).append("<li>"+lines[j]+"</li>");`

Comment: Right now the issue is blank space is shown to occupy 1 space when I try length of the lines[j].I tried checking against 1 whitespace instead of undefined and '' .But still did not work

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
            if((lines[j]!='') && (  lines[j]!='undefined'));

                $('#Text'+i).append("<li>"+lines[j]+"</li>");
```

To:

```
 if((lines[j]!='') && (  lines[j]!='undefined'))
{
     $('#Text'+i).append("<li>"+lines[j]+"</li>");
}
```

i.e. put your code in the body of the if statement

Comment: sorry for a mistake on my part I had changed that mistake issue is not that.See when I try to print the string length.It shows 1 even when there is a empty or undefined .But still its not even a white space .I tried to find if its a single whitespace but its not.Sorry for not changing the code before posting it .I am working on notepad++ and have been writing on multiple copies .

Comment: Try alerting the values. Maybe you will have an unexpected 1-char length value somewhere

Comment: yeah thats what I did first . the blank always showed empty alert without a message thats when I decided to check the length of alert .But it was 1 never 0 .But I cannot understand when no white space exists how can it be length 1

Comment: try alerting txt.responseText to look for other characters besides "\n".  Also try adding .trim() after each spot you call lines[j]

Comment: its breaks when txt becomes undefined and then undefined. causes error .I was tracking everything in console after a while I got its hard.I am now thinking of doing the stuff with python in backend itself

Comment: If txt is undefined then doesn't that mean you're not even getting data from that file path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154193/discussion-between-sachin-divakar-and-anthony-mcgrath).

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.trim()` or `$.trim()` to remove space.

```
var filename="../static/R6scoreex/extract/B&W1.txt"
    $.get(filename,function(txt){
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        len = lines.length;
        for (var j = 0 ; j < len; j++) {
            //save(lines[i]);
            var trimedLine = jQuery.trim(lines[j]);
            if((trimedLine != '') && (  trimedLine != 'undefined')){

                $('#Text'+i).append("<li>"+ trimedLine +"</li>");

        }

    });
```